# How to get key of a value in python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Dictionary values are lists:

```
dictionary_1 = {"ABC": [1,2,3], "DEF":[4,5,6]}
```

How do I get key of `5`, which is `"DEF"` from `dictionary_1` in python?

Comment: Do you mean you have an input of `5` and you want to return `"DEF"`? Or the other way around?

Comment: You probably want to use a two-way dictionary: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bidict/0.1.1

Comment: @lc. yes, I have `5`, and I want to get its key (which id "DEF").

Comment: @simonzack that question's answers don't look like answers posted below. because they are not duplicates.

Comment: @alwbtc: yet they are closely related. Check the linked posts in the sidebar too.

Answer (score 2):

You can create *reverse* dict:

```
>>> d = {i:k for k,v in dictionary_1.items() for i in v}
>>> d
{1: 'ABC', 2: 'ABC', 3: 'ABC', 4: 'DEF', 5: 'DEF', 6: 'DEF'}
>>> d[5]
'DEF'
```

Comment: Provided the values are unique..

Comment: This is a nice one because the op wanted to default to a key `GHJ` (in comments to my answer). So you can just call `d.get(5, "GHJ")`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this?

```
my_value = 5
for k, v in dictionary_1.iteritems():
    if my_value in v:
        print k
        break
else:
    print "No key, defaulting to GHJ"
```

Demo:

```
    In [12]: my_value = 8

    In [13]: for k, v in dictionary_1.iteritems():
        if my_value in v:
            print "Key for %s is %s" % (my_value, k)
            break
    else:
        print "No key found for %s, defaulting to GHJ" % my_value

    No key found for 8, defaulting to GHJ
```

Comment: If item is not found in dictionary, then it should return a default value, like "GHJ". How would you do it above?

Comment: @alwbtc updated my answer. It's for/else pattern, if the key is not found, the code will never `break` and the `else` clause is executed.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to search through the dictionary for that:

```
try:
    key = next(k for k, v in dictionary_1.iteritems() if 5 in v)
except StopIteration:
    raise KeyError('Key for 5 not found')
```

This assumes you are looking for **a** key. To find *all* keys you can use a list comprehension:

```
keys = [k for k, v in dictionary_1.iteritems() if 5 in v]
```

where the list could be empty.

Comment: @alwbtc: If you want default value, use this `key = next((k for k, v in d.iteritems() if 9 in v), 'GHJ')` and remove try..except.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is:

```
dictionary_1 = {"ABC": [1,2,3], "DEF":[4,5,6]}
for k, v in dictionary_1.items():
    if 5 in v:
        print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can check if 5 is in [4,5,6] list, you can also try:

```
dictionary_1 = {"ABC": [1,2,3], "DEF":[4,5,6]}

print dictionary_1.keys()[dictionary_1.values().index([4,5,6])]
```